# Element obscured when Selenium testing Edge webdriver for Azure Active Directory login Sign in to your account page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, coded-ui-tests, azure-active-directory

I'm using Selenium to make an integration test. Part of the test is the logon process that Microsoft Azure Active Directory [uses](http://logon.microsoftonline.com)

The test passes when using InternetExplorerWebDriver, but fails with EdgeWebDriver with the error:

> Element is obscured

The relevant part of the code:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
webDriver.Url = Settings.UrlHome();

var signInElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SignInLink"));
signInElement.Click();      

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("my_login_name")));
var loginLogoMicrosoft = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("my_login_name"));

loginLogoMicrosoft.Click();
```

The error occurs when executing the last Click(). I've tried several other elements, but none of them are working. Also 'inspect element' to determine which elements receives the click get this error when implementing in code.

How can I make the Microsoft Azure Active Directory logon process part of my Selenium test?

A same kind of issue is found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5238133/).

Comment: According to your link, it's a confirmed bug in EdgeDriver. Wait it out...

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code for filling out the Azure AD login form. The caveat is that when you fill the username field the "Sign In" button is disabled until some ajax operation is done in the background. The trick is to wait until there's a Sign In button on the page without this class.

```
private void SubmitLoginForm()
{
    var useAnotherAccount = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("use_another_account")).FirstOrDefault();

    if (useAnotherAccount != null)
    {
        useAnotherAccount.Click();
    }

    var loginInput = Driver.FindElements(By.Id(Site.Login.UserNameInput)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (loginInput != null)
    {
        loginInput.SendKeys(TestingData.UserName);
        loginInput.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
    }

    var passwordInput = Driver.FindElements(By.Id(Site.Login.PasswordInput)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (passwordInput != null)
    {
        passwordInput.Clear();
        passwordInput.SendKeys(TestingData.PassWord);
        passwordInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wait.Until(f => f.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#cred_sign_in_button:not(.disabled_button")));

    var loginButton = Driver.FindElements(By.Id(Site.Login.SigninButton)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (loginButton != null)
    {
        loginButton.Click();
        return;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not click the login button");
}
```

Comment: The main two lines which answers this question is the var wait = new etc... and wait.Until etc...